# why does matrix multiplication in mathematica not produce one single product matrix

Tags: matrix

How can I get one single product matrix? Please help!

[image]

Now: [image]

Comment: The trouble is that `MatrixForm` is only for visualizing the results.  Saying `c1 = List[{2, 9}, {7, 1}, {7, 8}]` is very different than saying `c1 = List[{2, 9}, {7, 1}, {7, 8}] // MatrixForm`.   To fix the issue, don't use `MatrixForm` when making assignments, only use it for displaying results.

Comment: So if I want to multiply C1 and D1, what command should I use?

Comment: `c1 = List[{2, 9}, {7, 1}, {7, 8}];
d1 = List[{4, 0, 9}, {1, 4, 5}];
result = d1.c1;
(* now use MatrixForm to print the result *)
MatrixForm @ result`

Comment: I typed in the exact same thing, and still got the two matrices. Why is that? Thank you so much Jason!

Answer (score 4):

`MatrixForm` wraps the matrix for display, preventing other operations from seeing it as a matrix. This is actually quite handy: you can display matrix calculations unevaluated. To allow them to proceed, just remove the wrapper:

```
c1.d1 /. MatrixForm -> Identity
(* {{17, 36, 63}, {29, 4, 68}, {36, 32, 103}} *)
```

Re-wrap the result in MatrixForm if you want it pretty.

Comment: Got it! Thank you John!