# Mathematica won't multiply a numeric matrix by a symbolic matrix

Tags: matrix

If

```
I1 = {{1,0},{1,-1}}
```

and

```
Acl = {{A , -B*K},{C*L, A-B*K-C*L}}
```

where A, B, C, and D are not defined in the notebook.  When I multiply the two matrices like this:

```
I1.Acl
```

Mathematica gives me the following:

[image: Not actually multiplied together]

Whereas if I don't multiply the I1 and Acl but multiply the contents of the variables directly (with parenthesis around each element of the matrice). Mathematica gives me the answer as I would expect. Like this:

[image: Desired form]

How can I multiply a two symbolic matrices together such that I get an answer that an actual matrice multiplication instead of just displaying what I asked Mathematica to do.  I'm sure this is a stupid question, but I searched Stack Exchange for 10 minutes using various search strings. In addition I searched  Youtube, and Google.

Wolfram alpha gives me the answer as I would have expected.  In the same form as if I had done the multiplication by hand.  Mathematica won't.

Mathematica Version 11.3

Comment: Note also that you shouldn't use upper-case symbols in Mathematica. Built-in functions always begin with upper-case letters; and so user-defined functions and all symbolic variables should use lower-case letters. For example, in your case, `C` and `K` have built-in meaning, which could lead to unexpected results (you can tell whether a variable has been assigned a value/definition by the colouring).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks your `I1` matrix is being used while wrapped in a `MatrixForm`.  Otherwise, it works just fine.

```
{{1, 0}, {1, -1}}.{{a, -b k}, {c l, a - b k - c l}}
```

> {{a, -b k}, {a - c l, -a + c l}}

```
MatrixForm[{{1, 0}, {1, -1}}].{{a, -b k}, {c l, a - b k - c l}}
```

[image]

That being said, one could also have

```
MatrixForm[{{1, 0}, {1, -1}}][[1]].{{a, -b k}, {c l, a - b k - c l}}
```

> {{a, -b k}, {a - c l, -a + c l}}

Comment: Oh shoot.  I did "wrap" it in MatrixForm.  I thought MatrixForm was just a formatting command.  I didn't think it did anything to my matrices.  Thank you for your reply.  That was it.

Comment: @frequencydrive If you find the answer useful, please consider *accepting* it as an answer.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/166709